# Image orientation by metadata-extractor

Tags: image, orientation, metadata-extractor

I am using "metadata-extractor" library to know image orientation, but every time I get orientation value as "1", which means no rotation is required even when source image is actually 90 degree rotated.

Am I missing something ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used some software to rotate the images? Not all software updates the metadata correctly when rotating the image data.

As a further test, do image viewing programs display the image with the correct rotation applied?